# Qt - getting "warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments"

Tags: c++, qt, warnings, qt-creator, literals

Keep getting warnings on lines like these

```
qDebug("An error occured while trying to create folder " + workdir.toAscii());
```

workdir being QString()

```
warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

Comment: +1 for enabling compiler warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should probably be:

```
qDebug("An error occured while trying to create folder %s", workdir.constData());
```

since [`qDebug`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6.2/qtglobal.html#qDebug) takes `const char*` as first argument.

Comment: now it throws 
   warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘class QByteArray’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime

and

  warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’

Comment: toAscii() returns a QByteArray, try workdir.toAscii().constData()

Comment: one can also use qPrintable(workdir), which is a bit shorter.

Comment: Or use the more friendly syntax: qDebug() << "An error occurred" << workdir; This requires including <QDebug>, but many Qt types have helpful overloads for operator<< and QDebugStream, as does QObject*

Answer (score 2):

When debbuging with `qDebug`, I find the following syntax much easier :

```
qDebug() << "An error occured while trying to create folder" << workdir;
```

To do this, you'll need to include the `<QtDebug>` header.

More info : [Qt docs regarding qDebug()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtglobal.html#qDebug).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work fine without warning like this :

```
qDebug("An error occurred while trying to create folder %s", qUtf8Printable(workdir));
```